# How to set prometheus rules in stable/prometheus chart values.yaml?

Tags: charts, configuration, yaml, rules, prometheus

Using official `Prometheus` chart `stable/prometheus`.

Customized its `values.yaml` file to set `alertmanager.yml` file and `serverFiles` area.

At `rules: {}`:

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L598

It's `{}`. How to write real alert rules as [official format](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) here?

For example, I tried:

```
  serverFiles:
    alerts: {}
    rules:
    # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
    - alert: InstanceDown
      expr: up == 0
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: page
      annotations:
        summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
```

And ran `$ helm install my_prometheus`. Then pod got this error:

```
PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "sweet-terrier-prometheus-server"
Back-off restarting failed container
Error syncing pod
```

Answer (score 10):

```
serverFiles:
  alerts:
    groups:
    - name: NodeAlerts
      rules:
      - alert: NodeCPUUsage
        expr: (100 - (avg(irate(node_cpu{mode="idle"}[5m])) BY (instance) * 100)) > 75
        for: 2m
        labels:
          severity: alert
        annotations:
          description: '{{$labels.instance}}: CPU usage is above 75% (current value is:
            {{ $value }})'
          summary: '{{$labels.instance}}: High CPU usage detect
```

rules are for record rules, alert is for alert rules.

> https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/rules/

Comment: Instead of modifying `values.yaml` is there a way to "inject" the rules during helm installation or upgrade? Like add the rules in a file or somehow?

Comment: @alex did you find a solution?

Comment: @MikeBevz  been a long time since I worked with this - I don't think I did but I didn't try very hard