# How to include prometheus rules from another yaml file in stable/prometheus chart values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Hi I am new to Kubernetes and Helm Chart. A similar question has been asked and answered here ([How to set prometheus rules in stable/prometheus chart values.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457047/how-to-set-prometheus-rules-in-stable-prometheus-chart-values-yaml))

But I am looking for a way to have the rules defined in another file, and then include the file in the `values.yaml`, for easier maintenance (since I have more than 2000+ lines of alerts...)

In particular, this is what I have in my `values.yaml`:

```
serverFiles:
  alerts:
    groups:
    - name: kubernetes-apps
      rules:
      - alert: KubePodCrashLooping
        annotations:
          message: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} ({{ $labels.container
            }}) is restarting {{ printf "%.2f" $value }} times / 5 minutes.
          runbook_url: https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodcrashlooping
        expr: rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{component="kube-state-metrics"}[15m])
          * 60 * 5 > 0
        for: 1h
        labels:
          severity: critical
... 
<2000 more lines>
...
  rules: {}
  prometheus.yml:
    rule_files:
      - /etc/config/rules
      - /etc/config/alerts
```

And this is what I'd like to achieve in the new `values.yaml`:

```
serverFiles:
  alerts: {{ include from values-alerts.yaml }}
  rules: {}
  prometheus.yml:
    rule_files:
      - /etc/config/rules
      - /etc/config/alerts
```

And this is the `values-alerts.yaml` file that I'd like to include in `values.yaml`:

```
alerts:
  groups:
  - name: kubernetes-apps
    rules:
    - alert: KubePodCrashLooping
      annotations:
        message: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} ({{ $labels.container
          }}) is restarting {{ printf "%.2f" $value }} times / 5 minutes.
        runbook_url: https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodcrashlooping
      expr: rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{component="kube-state-metrics"}[15m])
        * 60 * 5 > 0
      for: 1h
      labels:
        severity: critical
... 
<2000 more lines>
...
```

Please advise if this is doable, or if there is other better approach to do so.

Thank you,

Comment: Did the solution below get you the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to duplicate the code outlined in your last code snippet and you don't want to add default values to the snippet itself, am I right?

If that's the case, then you shouldn't use the `values.yaml`. 
The `values.yaml` file should contain default values for things like key-value-pairs for your templates.

However, you can include `templates` in `templates` as outlined in the [helm guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#declaring-and-using-templates-with-define-and-template) (comments after ###):

```
### Define a template (this can be a seperate file)
{{- define "mychart.labels" }}  
  labels:
    generator: helm
    date: {{ now | htmlDate }}
{{- end }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
  {{- template "mychart.labels" }} ### Include the template
```

Yields:

```
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: running-panda-configmap
  labels:
    generator: helm
    date: 2016-11-02
```

So instead of `including` the `values-alert` in `values.yaml` you can `include` the file in the `templates/` you need and `{{ template }}` out the labels.

**Don't forget the indentations, and that `helm template` is your friend!**